# getting specific key from a json format in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a specific key vulnerabilityID and vulnerabilitySoln from this json file.  This is towards the bottom of the json script.

```
{
   "vulnerabilities": [
      {
         "labels": [
            {
               "labelKey": "com.acme.image.source",
               "labelValue": "http://github.com/base-image.git"
            },
            {
               "labelKey": "BA",
               "labelValue": "abc"
            },
            {
               "labelKey": "OwnerContact",
               "labelValue": "john.doe@gmail.com"
            }
         ],
         "repositoryDigest": [
            {
               "digest": "9089",
               "repository": "frost/micro",
               "registry": "artifactory.acme.com"
            }
         ],
         "artifactorySha": "4324",
         "imageID": "er34342",
         "createdTimestamp": "2022-10-17",
         "engineeringEID": "afd343",
         "vulnerabilities": [
            {
               "test1": "12444",
               "test2": "433w",
               "vulnerabilityID": "12345",
               "vulnerabilitySoln": "http://website.com"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the code that i attempted

```
import json
import smtplib


with open("dummy.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

def vulnData():
    for i in data["vulnerabilities"]:
        vulnID = (i["vulnerabilities"]["vulnerabilityID"])
        vulnSoln = (i["vulnerabilities"]["vulnerabilitySoln"])
        print(vulnID, vulnSoln)

vulnData()
```

This is the error output I am getting -- TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Please suggest any ideas how i can get specific value.

```
    vulnID = (i["vulnerabilities"]["vulnerabilityID"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `vulnID = (i[0]["vulnerabilities"]["vulnerabilityID"])`. `i` is a list of dicts, so you need to access the first item in the list.

Comment: @MattDMo Now I am getting  `vulnID = (i[0]["vulnerabilities"]["vulnerabilityID"])
KeyError: 0`.  Also, I don't want to hard code 0 because this json can change in the future. Is there a way to not use 0?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Do you know how to index lists? If not, do a Python tutorial. On the other hand, if you want to loop over the list items, what's stopping you from doing that? Next, this is not valid JSON; it's missing closing brackets and two of the values are malformed. For getting help on SO, you need to make a [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: BTW, "vulnerabilitySoln" has a typo in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are also two levels of lists in there:

```py
def vulnData():
    for i in data["vulnerabilities"]:
        vuln = i["vulnerabilities"][0]
        vulnID = vuln["vulnerabilityID"]
        vulnSoln = vuln["vulnerabilitySoln"])
        print(vulnID, vulnSoln)
```